# NER - Should I include common prefixes in labeled entities

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to recognize entities in a set of OCR texts from images of documents. Since the text is commonly in the form `some_label: value` in the document, it comes up often (but not always) in the OCR text as well.

My question is, say I am trying to annotate dates in my OCR text files, and 80% of times the date is in the format `Date: xx/xx/xxxx`; would it better if I ...

1. Only marked `xx/xx/xxxx` as my date entity

   - Represents the true entity
   - Would be representative of 100% of the data
2. *OR* marked the entire `Date: xx/xx/xxxx` as my date entity

   - Would take advantage of the commonly occurring `Date:`  prefix for better accuracy?

#### Another example:

Amounts are commonly represented as `$xxxxxx5.37` and `$ 63.75`

1. Choose `5.37` and `63.75`
2. Choose `$xxxxxx5.37` and `$ 63.75` (taking advantage of $ sign)

Which of these would be the better practice to follow / lead to a better model?

(P.S.: I'm using Prodigy to annotate my data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the neural network architecture you use.

Let's assume you use spaCy v2 and its default neural architecture which is a CNN.
In this case, the architecture is going to slide through your text according to a specific window (i.e. x number of words before the `date` entity and x number of words after the `date` entity).

With this approach, every time the token `Date:` appears in the text, it is likely that the neural network will recognize that the entity `date` sits next to it.

In this case, my suggestion would be to include only the annotate the xx/xx/xxxx date as an entity. It will give the model more flexibility in determining what is a date `entity`. However, testing is always the best way to find out what's best. So, give it a try :)